# Which is more profitable if I have big hashrate?

Tags: mining-pools, hashrate, solo-mining, mining-profitability

Which is more profitable if I have big hashrate - solo or pool?

My hashrate is around 39 kH/s in total from all the devices.

And I'm able to run a full node 24/7

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get a little more with solo mining as you won't have to pay the pool fee, but your income will be much less regular because of the higher variance.

Comment: I see. So income will only depend on blockfinding, right?

Comment: Yes, you'll get the block reward, but only when you find a block.